# Oracle SQL. How to execute query one by one

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Could you help me, **how can I execute query one by one in Oracle SQL Developer?**

When there's one query system works correctly.

But when I write 2 or more and press "ctrl"  + "enter", System marks out all queries and trying to execute all of them.

Comment: in PLSQL developer we just highlight the query and press F8 to execute.

Comment: Are you talking about the difference between the 'run' and 'run script' commands?

Comment: I am talking about just "run statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate each query by semi-colon, then SQL Developer executes them one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

If no text is selected, Ctrl + Enter will execute only the query the insertion point is currently on. I just verified it.

If more than one query is selected, it will run all queries that are selected.